# ADBs is unresponsive aftre 5000ms ! killing server and retrying when i run ionic liveserver

Tags: android, ionic-framework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOMAW.png)
when I run ionic live server I find that error
I try in another phone worked but in my phone don't work
my phone is Samsung galaxy A11

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Did you find any solution?